# neo4j build relationship within same label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have data like  below in .csv files

```
uid fid  
1   2  
1   3  
2   3
```

How can I create

1. nodes based on uid
2. bidirectional relationship in a label called "user" besed on the uid and fid

with cypher?

I try something like

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT  
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:xxx.csv" AS csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR "\t"   
merge (usr:User{uid: toInt(csvLine.uid)})-[:friendof]-(frd:User { fid: toInt(csvLine.fid)})
```

but it doesn't work like I expected.
Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The neo4j has no concept of a bi-directional relationship, it always has a one direction (The direction can be ignored if it is not important for the application).

2) Do not use the property `fid`. Use only one property for all nodes: `uid`.

3) To exclude the creation of extra nodes, first merge nodes, and then the relationship:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT  
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///xxx.csv" AS csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR "\t"   
merge (usr1:User { uid: toInt(csvLine.uid)})
merge (usr2:User { uid: toInt(csvLine.fid)})
merge (usr1)-[:friendof]-(usr2)
```